# Chef - Skip resources from status of previous run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, provisioning, cookbook

For server rebuild, I want to skip some section of my cookbook according to the results of a previous run.

For instance, we have a resource to start Weblogic servers.

```
weblogic_server "server_name" do 
    action :start
end
```

These startups take a lot of time during the build. I want to skip this if it was run succesfully in the last build, to avoid having to wait too much for the rebuild. Something like this:

```
weblogic_server "server_name" do 
    action :start
    not_if { it_was_run_successfully_during_the_previous_run }
end
```

I know the best way to do it would be have script checking on weblogic servers status, but that's up to another team and I need a temporary solution.

I thought about a logfile in JSON format referencing the different steps of the build.

**e.g:**

```
{
    "provisioning"          : true,
    "start_weblogic_servers : true,
    "configuring_ohs"       : false
}
```

In this case I would have a template resource for this logfile and then update the values during the run. Then in every run I would check this file first and skip the right section according to the values I find.

Is there a better way to go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nabeel Amjad solution worked for me. Follow these steps:

**Create a `file` resource with `action :nothing`**

```
file '/tmp/logfile' do
    action: nothing
end
```

**Set your resource to notify the `file` resource after running**

```
weblogic_server 'server_name' do 
    action   :start
    notifies :create, 'file[/tmp/logfile]', :immediately
end
```

**Add a guard `not_if` that will skip future execution of this resource if the file exists on the server**

```
weblogic_server 'server_name' do 
    action   :start
    notifies :create, 'file[/tmp/logfile]', :immediately
    not_if   { ::File.exist?('/tmp/logfile') }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past is to just create an empty file, if it exists then you skip it (`not_if do ::File.exists?('/path/to/some_empty_file') end`). You could then have some code when a build is successful or not to either create or delete these files, I realise it is probably not the best approach but it has worked for me as long as I can remember.

If you really want then you could have some script checking the server status (say on a 5 minute interval) and then adjusting that empty file accordingly (by deleting it or keeping it).